# Writing code in c++ and it skips some

Tags: command-line, bash, c++, qt-creator

Sorry if the title was a little confusing. What I'm doing is creating a simple app to install certain programs in ubuntu. A friend wanted me to do this for him so he will have all of his apps in one place that he likes and it's giving me some practice in c++. I'm using QT Creator as my IDE and c++ as the language..here is my code:

```
system("gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'sudo apt install bleachbit; read -p PressAnyKeyToExit...; exit; exec bash'");
```

My problem is that installing a program works but it totally bypasses the read -p command and just goes to exit. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly because on Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is the `dash` shell - whose `read` builtin AFAIK doesn't support a `-p` option.

Comment: thanks for the help! i just changed "sh" in the code to "bash" and it worked!